# How to merge to MySQL tables based on id

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Let's say I have three tables like these:

table name:

```
id | name  
1  | Bob  
2  | Alice  
3  | Bryan  
etc
```

table pants:

```
id | size  
1  | S  
3  | M
```

table skirt:

```
id | size  
2  | M
```

How do I merge the three tables using MySQL and obtain a table like this:
result table:

```
id | name | pants | skirt  
1  | Bob  |  S    |      
2  | Alice|       | M  
3  | Bryan|  M    |
```

When there's no matching id, the cell will just be blank.

Comment: What did you try so far? How are the sizes and people connected?

Comment: join query on the ids

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Join the tables with a `left join`. Like this:

```
SELECT
    tablename.id,
    tablename.name,
    tablepants.size AS pants,
    tableskirt.size as skirt
FROM
    tablename
    LEFT JOIN tablepants
        on tablename.id=tablepants.id
    LEFT JOIN tableskirt
        ON tablename.id=tableskirt.id
```

Comment: Or `INNER JOIN` depending on what you want.

Comment: If you want the result as the OP. Then I think that a `LEFT JOIN` is the way to go